# SSIS Lookup Match Output Column has a precision that is not valid

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion

I used to have a working SSIS package. Then I changed the database column data type from MONEY to DECIMAL(23,5). I edited the SSIS package XML manually to change the data type in the lookup ReferenceMetadataXml. I also CAST the SQL query columns to DECIMAL(23,5).

The problem is that I still get an validation error:

```
The LookupName.Outputs[Lookup Match Output].Columns[ColumnName] has a precision that is not valid. The precision must be between 1 and 38.
```

My ReferenceMetadataXml in SSIS package looks like this:

```
referenceColumn name="ColumnName" dataType="DT_DECIMAL" length="28" precision="28" scale="5" codePage="0"
```

And the SqlCommand has a CAST like this:

```
CAST(DbTable.ColumnName AS DECIMAL(28,5)) ColumnName
```

To me the precision should be fine, but what am I missing? I'm not too familiar with SSIS so there's a good chance that there is something that I have missed.

Comment: Why did you edit it manually? Why not just open the package and let BIDS autocorrect the metadata?

Comment: Good question. I thought I could just change the type easier directly from the XML. I started editing the package in the editor and got it working. Had to change several steps and re-create some as the metadata wasn't refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Nick suggested, the problem was solved by opening the package and letting BIDS to autocorrect the metadata.

I originally hesitated to use this method as my package configuration made it a bit difficult to configure the database connection at design time. Eventually I got it solved by using a separate design time connections. The change caused a lot of steps to be changed but I got it working.

Editing the package XML manually is not suggested, even if it seems like a small change.